Is it possible to use relative paths to files in PhpStorm scratches
I'm trying to use the "import" and "run" commands in .http scratches, but I don't understand how to use a relative path in standard scratches directory "Scratches and Consoles" (in file system ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2024.3/scratches).
Absolute path works correctly, but relative path works only in the project directory.




